# Mass Edit in lightning redirect to salesforce classic got an error 'URL No Longer Exists'

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lighting-web-component

**In Lightning**

[image: Mass Edit In Lightning]

Error : **'URL No Longer Exists'**

[image: URL No Longer Exists]

Component :

> Portal_OpportunityMassEditRedirector.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div width="100%" style="text-align: center">
    <h2>Loading</h2>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller :

> Portal_OpportunityMassEditRedirectorController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    
    var pageName = '/masseditopportunity?id=' + component.get("v.recordId");
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": pageName,
        "isredirect" : false
    });

    urlEvent.fire();
    },
})
```

**In Experience Cloud Sites**

[image: Mass Edit In Experience Cloud Sites]

After Clicked on Mass Edit

[image: Result : Show Opportunity Product]

I want the result in lightning as same as sites result, but unexpectedly I got an error 'URL No Longer Exists' when I clicked on Mass Edit in lightning. 
Can someone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Is there any custom page with name masseditopportunity?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala how could I see the custom page?

Comment: Can you check in your visualforce pages or aura components with that name?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I am new to salesforce sir

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala There is no name with masseditopportunity in visualforce pages